# Xaml doesn't know which objects are defined in a different assembly

Tags: xaml

As I add a class in some non `UI` assembly and use it in some `xaml` in UI `assembly` get the following error:

```
Provide value on 'System.Windows.StaticResourceExtension' threw an exception.' Line number '22' and line position '55
```

Inner Exception:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'XXX, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.":"XXX, PublicKeyToken=null
```

StackTrace:
   `at System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.RewrapException(Exception e, IXamlLineInfo lineInfo, Uri baseUri)
   at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.Load(XamlReader xamlReader, IXamlObjectWriterFactory writerFactory, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlObjectWriterSettings settings, Uri baseUri)
   at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.LoadBaml(XamlReader xamlReader, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlAccessLevel accessLevel, Uri baseUri)
   at System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.LoadBaml(Stream stream, ParserContext parserContext, Object parent, Boolean closeStream)
   at System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(Object component, Uri resourceLocator)
   at Pouyansoft.SellEngineering.MVVM.WPF.Letters.View.SelectLetterTemplateView.InitializeComponent() in d:\NirooTeamProject\NirooTransTeamProject\SellEngineering\Pouyansoft.SellEngineering.MVVM.WPF.Letters\View\SelectLetterTemplateView.xaml:line 1
   at Pouyansoft.SellEngineering.MVVM.WPF.Letters.View.SelectLetterTemplateView..ctor() in D:\NirooTeamProject\NirooTransTeamProject\SellEngineering\Pouyansoft.SellEngineering.MVVM.WPF.Letters\View\SelectLetterTemplateView.xaml.cs:line 23`

The funny thing is if I just create a single instance of the mentioned object somewhere in `Code Behind` it works correctly.

Comment: Can you post the XAML you use for the {StaticResource } and the XAML imports? Perhaps you are missing the XAML imports?

Comment: Hi, did you ever find a solution to this? I've just updated to VS2015 and am now getting this error.